# Pushing Laravel project to digitalocean

Tags: laravel, git, server, digital-ocean

I created an Ubuntu droplet in digitalocean and installed Nginx, PHP and Mysql, I created bare git repository and connected to it remotely to push my local project, when I push my project it shows me that uploaded successfully but when I enter my server and access my project path the folder is empty.

**I followed below guide link**
https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/

Comment: Did you tried git cloning ?

Answer (score 0):

Like you say: your repository is a `bare` repository, therefore you only see data being populated in the .git folder itself.

You need to `clone` that bare repository to the folder you want your Laravel app to be installed. This way, your bare repository remains the `remote` (origin) repository, and your clone is the `local` repository (even though they are in the same "remote" server).